# Azure Pubsub Events on Server

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, websocket

I'm trying to get an [Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/tutorial-build-chat?tabs=csharp) working with pubsub. I can't get the server endpoint that handles the calls from the pubsub service to work.

This is the code for Program.cs to wireup the end points:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/negotiate", async (WebPubSubServiceClient<Sample_ChatApp> serviceClient, HttpContext context) =>
    {
        var id = context.Request.Query["id"];
        if (id.Count != 1)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("missing user id");
            return;
        }
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(serviceClient.GetClientAccessUri(userId: id).AbsoluteUri);
    });

    endpoints.MapWebPubSubHub<Sample_ChatApp>("/eventhandler/{*path}");

    endpoints.MapGet("/msg", async (WebPubSubServiceClient<Sample_ChatApp> serviceClient, HttpContext context) =>
    {
        await serviceClient.SendToAllAsync("test");
    });
});
```

When hitting the endpoint I get the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint: '/eventhandler'. Please register the EndpointMiddleware using 'IApplicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(...)' if using routing.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder+c.b__18_0(HttpContext context)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint: '/eventhandler'. Please register the EndpointMiddleware using 'IApplicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(...)' if using routing.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder+c.b__18_0(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.Azure.WebPubSub.AspNetCore.WebPubSubMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
```

I have to be missing something silly but I've been looking at this for hours and I've got no idea. I assumed there was a step I missed so I downloaded the demo but I get the same result with that version of the code.

Comment: Provided you have followed all the minute details in that tutorial, it should work. Have you check these [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/howto-local-debug-event-handler) steps ?

Comment: I did follow the tutorial and then I downloaded the demo itself and got the same error. I looked at that troubleshooting guide but unfortunately it's no help. It says check that the event handler is working. I know it's not working but I don't know why or how to fix it.

Comment: I have checked the official doc and can't reproduce the issue you mentioned. I think it maybe related to the version of .net sdk in your local pc, and pls upgrade the VS2022 to the latest version. Then test again.

Comment: My VS2022 Vesion : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.4.2             &&&&&&   .Net Version: dotnet --version
7.0.100

Answer (score 0):

I have double checked this issue, and please allow me to show you show to run this sample perfectly. The issue in your post, is missing some settings about the eventhandler in your azure portal.

**Test Result**

[image]

**Steps**

1. [Download the sample project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webpubsub/tree/main/samples/csharp/chatapp/) and open it.
2. Add the code like you about the "/msg".
3. Using ngrok and generate an accessable url. Command :

   ```
   ngrok http https://localhost:5001
   ```

   [image]
4. Check the generated url, is it working well
5. Add eventhandler in azure portal by using the generated url.

   [image]
6. Test result pic

   [image]